# Missing nodes and edges in OSM map using OSMNX

Tags: openstreetmap, osmnx

I am loading a graph of OSM roads using a polygon using the following command:

```
roads_graph = ox.graph_from_polygon(polygon_geom, network='all')
```

I also get road data with the following using the same polygon:

```
roads_gdf = ox.geometries_from_polygon(polygon_geom, tags={'highway': True})
```

When I compare the edges and nodes from the graph to the roads_gdf there are discrepancies (see figure below). Basically, there are road segments in roads_gdf that don't have corresponding nodes or edges in the graph (i.e, red road segments in figure). Btw, this is occurring in many places throughout the shapefile and I am just showing one area. It does appear that edges/nodes corresponding to a terminus are typically dropped although I have seen instances where other edges/nodes are dropped, too.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some OSM IDs of missing ways?

Comment: @gboeing Sure thing: 745683065, 885543145, 738127699, 5953394

Comment: These are all `highway=service` with `access=private`. Coincidence or intentional?

Comment: @scai I think you're right. It looks like nearly all of these missing nodes/edges are private driveways and service roads within residential apartment complexes, etc. Any ideas on how to include the private access roads?

Comment: Yes, see the answer I just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `network_type="all_private"` (the default argument) to also get access=private ways (the "all" network type only gets public ways). See docs for more: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_polygon

Comment: Thanks! It is a bit confusing that "all" isn't actually all. It would probably make more sense to have "all_public", "all_private" and "all" with the "all" corresponding to both public and private roads. But, probably not worth the effort! Thanks again.